# How to reinstall default Perl on Mac osx?

Tags: macos, perl, osx-mountain-lion

I accidently deleted the default Perl library on Mac OSX Mountain Lion. I know it was a stupid mistake, but how do I fix it? Whenever I try to use Perl I get

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib 
Referenced from: /usr/bin/perl5.12
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

What do I do so I can use Perl again?

Comment: Just restore from your backup (e.g. Time Machine).

Comment: do you get any output when you do a `perl -v` ?

Comment: I can't restore from a backup because I dont know when it happened. When I do perl -v I get that output. @TudorConstantin

Comment: Nuclear option: backup your data, reinstall osx, start using perlbrew and try not to touch system perl ever again

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal,

```
curl -L http://xrl.us/installperlosx | bash
```

Then quit terminal. You should be all set. Installation does take a few minutes.